# How to unit test new object creation in interface default method?

Tags: java, unit-testing, design-patterns, junit

There is a default method in the interface that creates new object and uses its functions. So I need to mock it. But I can't figure it out without making another default method which returns new instance. I used to make factories so far that handles object creation and than mock the factory method. But can't do it in interfaces since interfaces can't have instance variables which is factories in this scenario. Any other ideas? I want to be consistent in the project but now I have 2 different approach to avoid object creations in methods. Here is an example:

```
public interface ISomeInterface
{
    default Integer callMe( )
    {
        Object someObject = new Object( ); // need to mock this
        Integer result = someObject.finish();
        result = result + 1;

        return result;
    }
}
```

I used to refactor the code with factories when I don't use interface like this;

```
default Integer callMeNotInterfaceClass( )
{
    Object someObject = new Object( );
    Integer result = instanceFactory.create().finish(); // I can mock create() method 
    result = result + 1;

    return result;
}
```

Only solution I implemented so for wrapper method:

```
public Integer callMe( )
{
    Object someObject = new Object( );
    Integer result = wrapperMethodCall.finish(); // only solution so far. But now I have 2 different approaches in the project to avoid object creation.
    result = result + 1;

    return result;
}

default Object wrapperMethodCall() {
    return new SomeObject().someMethodsToBeMocked();
}
```

Comment: 2 approaches might be warranted still. If you don't like having two, pick one.

Comment: If the type of `someObject` has been tested, I don't see why testing would be needed here, as you'd be testing an assignment & addition, which have already been thoroughly tested. Assuming your real case is more complex, you'd typically want to separate how the data is obtained (instantiation) from how the data is used (calls) - not only would you be able to test the logic by injecting a mock, but you'd also gain flexibility of being able to swap implementations in production code (assuming the type isn't final, allowing for future implementations).

Comment: @VinceEmigh my mistake while creating sample example. wrapperMethodCall instantiates new SomeObject(). Yes as I said in the question, that is how I used to, instantation is done by factories and code can be tested easily. But in the interfaces, I can't do that since I can't hold a SomeFactory instance in the interface, I need to create new SomeFactory() in the method again

Comment: @cmlonder You don't need a factory, you need to allow clients to specify where the data is coming from. Even with a factory, you'd still be mixing how the data is obtained (factory) with how the data is used, thus you'd still have to allow the client to specify the factory used. You should separate it by allowing the client to specify which object to use. You could then expose a method which instantiates a default implementation, passing it into the method with all the logic.

Comment: @VinceEmigh I got it. You mean I need one more method in the interface like getObject():IForcedObjectIntefrace, so client implements IForcedObjectIntefrace and provides it to me in the implementation of ISomeInterface:getObject method. And I can use getObject().finish() method. Right?

Comment: You'd have `callMe(Object)`, which you'd test by passing in a mock. Beyond testing, this gives clients flexibility in what implementation will be used. You could then have a `callMe()` which instantiates the default implementation and passes it to `callMe(Object)`, so clients aren't forced to supply their own implementation if they don't have one/want to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As usual, unit tests force you to think of the design of your classes.

First, you should notice that you have two main different type of objects.

Some objects are values: they are immutable, can exist in multiple copies, are comparable (and have a `hashCode` too). This is the kind of objects that are easy to store in a database. If you know a bit of Kotlin, you've heard of the [`data classes`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html): that's it.

Some other objects that have the semantic of an entity: they are mutable, it doesn't make sense to compare them and often you have only one copy of them. They are the objects that *do* something.

The objects that have the semantic of an entity are the ones you need to mock in unit tests, whereas you don't need to mock the values. To pass the mocks, these objects have to be injected in the classes, as parameters of the constructor.

In your snippet, you created in a function an object that seems to have the semantic of an entity (a value doesn't `finish` anything) and that's why you have a problem: you can't unit test because you can't mock this entity.

The solution is simple: either you inject the object in the method:

```
public interface ISomeInterface
{
    default Integer callMe(Object someObject)
    {
        Integer result = someObject.finish();
        result = result + 1;

        return result;
    }

    ...
}
```

Or you inject the object in the class:

```
public interface ISomeInterface
{
    default Integer callMe()
    {
        Integer result = finishObject();
        result = result + 1;

        return result;
    }

    // classes will need an instance of the object to implement this
    Integer finishObject(); 

    ...
}
```

In both cases, classes that implements your interface have either the responsibility to provide the object itself when they call the method or to return value of the `finish` method.

But remember: if you create the object in a method of those classes, unit testing them will become difficult too. Use the factory pattern to create entity objects in a static method and pass thoses object to the constructor.

Unit testing of classes and methods will become easier if you follow this rule of thumbs: when the object has a semantic value, and create it at the higher level (`main` if possible) and pass it as a parameter of your constructors or methods.